# Formatting caption so it doesn't run off the table width

Tags: tables, captions

I created the following table, which showed up nicely in the document on its own:

```
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \caption{MyCaption}

    --data goes here--

    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

However, after I integrated it within my document, it completely runs off the right side of the page. How do I get it to keep its size?

Edit: it's a very small table, 4 columns, so the size isn't the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
%\input{MyChapter}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Performance scores from assessments of divergent and convergent thinking tests of creativity and non-creativity (control task).}

\begin{tabular}{c{3cm}c{1cm}c{1cm}c{1cm}}
\hline
Variable & \textit{N} & \textit{M} & \textit{SD}\\
\hline
XYZ & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill\\
XXX & 17 & 222 & 2222\\
XXX & 22 & 111 & 11\\
XXX & 22 & 111 & 111\\
XXX & 22 & 111 & 111\\
XYZ & \hfill & \hfill & \hfill\\
XXX & 111 &  & 12\\
XXX & 111 & 2 & 1\\
\hline
\label{table:1}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I think it might be that the caption is too long. How do I get it to stay the same width as the table?

Comment: Welcome to the site :) In order to answer this question, I strongly suspect we will need to see just how you "integrated it within your document". And, in fact, the structure of the document is probably the important bit, could you provide a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: your table is simple to wide to be fit in text or column width. to be able help you, I encourage you to consider @Au101 comment!

Comment: does this help? sorry I'm still new to this so if you need more info please direct me to it

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{carletonthesis}

\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\input{MyChapters}

\bibliography{MyBib}


-the table is in one of the chapters-

\end{document}

Comment: And table? Problem is in it, doesn't it?

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. For code-blocks indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: You must get tex errors from `c{3cm}` the syntax is either `c` or `p{3cm}` `c` does not take a width. If you get tex errors don't even look at the pdf, fix the errors first.

Comment: unrelated but using an option of `[!ht]` greatly increases the chance that the table floats to the end of the document. Is there any particular reason to prevent the table being placed on a float page?

Comment: if I replace `c{...}` column type with`p{...}`, i get table which doesn't protrude out of text. It is not centered in text but the caption, which has two lines, has width equal to text width. What is actually your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you looking something like this:

[image]

Above image of table is generated by:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Performance scores from assessments of divergent and convergent thinking tests of creativity and non-creativity (control task).}
\label{table:1}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
    \hline
Variable    & \textit{N} & \textit{M} & \textit{SD}\\
    \hline
XYZ         &           &           &           \\
XXX         & 17        & 222       & 2222      \\
XXX         & 22        & 111       & 11        \\
XXX         & 22        & 111       & 111       \\
XXX         & 22        & 111       & 111       \\
XYZ         &           &           &           \\
XXX         & 111       &           & 12        \\
XXX         & 111       & 2         & 1         \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In my MWE I use package `showframe` only for showing page layout. In real use it had to be removed.

To force caption to be the same width as table, I use package `threeparttable`. It enables to include `caption` in table. By this the caption is nod wider than table. Additionally, you can add to table list of (foot)notes, if you have them in table.

In my MWE I use `p{...}` column type instead unknown `c`. If you like to have centered cells contents, than you can define new column type, for example`c{...}` as

```
\newcolumntype{c}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

I didn't figured out of purpose `\hfill` in many of your table cells, so I remove them.